# How to create a set up project for a C# windows application, in VS 2005?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, installation, setup-project

HI, I have a C# windows application. I need to create a set up project for this solution. Can someone kindly help me with steps to create a set up project. I need to create and add a set up project to the solution, where my windows application sits. This is the 1st time I am creating a set up project.

Thnaks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you add a setup project to an existing solution:

1. Right-click on your solution in the Solution Explorer.
2. From the context menu, point to "Add" and select "New Project".
3. In the "Add New Project" dialog, expand "Other Project Types" in the left-hand treeview, expand "Setup and Deployment", and select "Visual Studio Installer".
4. Select "Setup Wizard" in the list of choices on the right.
5. Type a name for your setup project at the bottom, and then click "OK".
6. A [wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kay7az51.aspx) will appear that will guide you through creating a setup project for your application.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the information you provided. I could successfully create a set up project, added primary output of my Windows appl to set up project and BUILT the entire solution. But I HAVE A QUERY THAT WHERE WILL THE INSTALLER FILE BE PLACED AFTER I BUILD THE ENTIRE SOLUTION (WITH BOTH aPPLICATION & SET UP PROJ). i AM NOT ABLE TO FIND THE INSTALLER FILE, SO THAT ON DOUBLE CLICKING THIS INSTALLER FILE i CAN INSTALL MY APPLICATION ONTO MY SYSTEM.     kINDLY HELP ME WITH THIS.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c(v=VS.100).aspx

To create a new setup project

1. On the File menu, point to Add
   Project, and then click New Project.
2. In the resulting Add New Project
   dialog box, select the Setup and
   Deployment Projects folder.
3. Choose Setup Project for a standard
   setup, or Web Setup Project for a
   Web.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the information you provided. I could successfully create a set up project, added primary output of my Windows appl to set up project and BUILT the entire solution. But I HAVE A QUERY THAT WHERE WILL THE INSTALLER FILE BE PLACED AFTER I BUILD THE ENTIRE SOLUTION (WITH BOTH aPPLICATION & SET UP PROJ). i AM NOT ABLE TO FIND THE INSTALLER FILE, SO THAT ON DOUBLE CLICKING THIS INSTALLER FILE i CAN INSTALL MY APPLICATION ONTO MY SYSTEM. kINDLY HELP ME WITH THIS